# How can I behave with a column as unique without having index?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a column, but I need to check new value **shouldn't** be exist in the table. Based on some reason, I cannot create an *unique-index* on that column. So how can I handle that by the query?

```
UPDATE mytable SET col = :val WHERE id = :id;
```

Well how can I check `:val` doesn't exist in the `col` column before updating?

Comment: 'Based on some reason, I cannot create an unique-index on that column' It's possible you can't create the unique index because there is already a duplicate in your table.. did you check for that?

Comment: @BrianGlaz No no .. my table is empty right now. I don't want to create a unique index on that column because {Long Store} `:-)`

Comment: Write a trigger to check whether the new value exists or not first.

Comment: make it a unique index stack. Otherwise you are going to write some kloodgie thing to do the same that may be faulty.

Comment: If you're doing this frequently on a database of non-trivial size you really want a `UNIQUE` constraint. Doing a manual scan will get incrementally slower as your database grows to the point of being insufferably bad. An index imposes some additional write overhead, but testing uniqueness is extremely inexpensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a simple NOT EXISTS subselect like you can do in other SQL languages.  However you can do a cross join to a virtual table that checks for the existence of val and prevent a update from occurring if the virtual table is has a result.

```
UPDATE mytable AS tb1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 `valExsits` FROM mytable WHERE col = :val LIMIT 1) AS tbTest
SET tb1.col = :val
WHERE tb1.id = :id AND tbTest.valExsits IS NULL
```

Comment: @Shadow, thank you for the heads up.  I should've paid attention to the Sql language.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Why `CROSSE JOIN` ?

Comment: I suppose I could've done a `LEFT JOIN`, but a cross join was more appropriate.  By using a cross join, If the virtual table doesn't return a row it won't prevent the results from mytable from being returned if id is matched.   If I did a inner join and there was no match that would've prevented the update since no row is returned from the virtual table.

Comment: @shadow a cross join is a cartesian product naming convention to alert people to the fact. For readability.

Comment: That said, if anyone were to use this answer in place of a unique index, I am glad I am not using that system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a not

```
  UPDATE mytable SET col = :val WHERE id = :id
  and  not(1 = ( select ifnull(max(1),0) from mytable where col = :val))  ;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot .. I did it now :-)